# SDL openGL issue, no openGL drawing seen

Tags: opengl, sdl

I am using cygwin SDL 1.2.15 using the latest cygwin

Here is my code using SDL and openGL

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_opengl.h>
#include <iostream>

size_t sx=600, sy=600, bpp=32;

void render(void) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();                                       // set location in front of camera
  //glTranslated(0, 0, -10);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);                                      // draw a square
       glColor3d(1, 0, 0);
       glVertex3d(-2,  2,  0);
       glVertex3d( 2,  2,  0);
       glVertex3d( 2, -2,  0);
       glVertex3d(-2, -2,  0);
   glEnd();

   glFlush();
   SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
   GLenum e;
   while ((e =glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR)
          std::cout<<"Error "<< e << std::endl;
}

int input(void) {
    SDL_Event event;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT || (event.type == SDL_KEYUP &&        event.key.keysym.sym     == SDLK_ESCAPE)) return 0;
   return 1; 
}
```

and this is my main function

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    SDL_Surface *surf;

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0) return 0;
    if (!(surf = SDL_SetVideoMode(sx, sy, bpp, SDL_OPENGL))) return 0;

    glViewport(0, 0, sx, sy);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0, (float)sx / (float)sy, 1.0, 100.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glClearDepth(1.0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GLenum e;
    while ((e =glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR)
          std::cout<<"Error "<< e << std::endl;

    for (;;) {
        if (!input()) break;
        render();
        SDL_Delay(10);
    }

    SDL_FreeSurface(surf);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

it compiles with no error but when I run it only the window shows up and now openGL rectangle..

Comment: [Don't `SDL_FreeSurface()` the `SDL_Surface*` returned by `SDL_SetVideoMode()`.](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_SetVideoMode#line-53)

Answer (score 0):

You have setup a near plane to one :

```
gluPerspective(45.0, (float)sx / (float)sy, 1.0/*near plane*/, 100.0);
```

Everything that is closer to the camera is clipped.

Your quad lies in plane z = 0. Try moving it a bit backward.

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);                                      // draw a square
   glColor3d(1, 0, 0);
   glVertex3d(-2,  2,  5);
   glVertex3d( 2,  2,  5);
   glVertex3d( 2, -2,  5);
   glVertex3d(-2, -2,  5);
glEnd();
```

I don't remember if Z is facing the camera, so you might need negative Z value.

You also need to pay attention to face culling. It might be better to deactivate it to be sure ( `glDisable( GL_CULL_FACE )`)

Comment: I tried both, negative and poitive values, and it still just a screen with a black sdl window.  Also, I have tried uncommenting the sdltranslated(0,0,-10);

Comment: Have you tried clearing the backbuffer with a color, this will verify everything's setup correctly

Comment: Assuming an identity view matrix, Z would need to be between -1 and -100 to be visible. Also, GL_CULL_FACE is disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the black color of the SDL window. Some times it renders the drawing with black color...may be this helps!